# Date count downs in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I was wondering if it is possible to create a formula in Google Sheets that counts down the days remaining in a month.

I would like the formula to go something like this:

`=(Date of end of month - Today())` = Days remaining in the month (as a #, not date)

So for today the output for today would be 24.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to format the cell as a Number (don't leave it as automatic).

So, if you put the date at the end of the month (e.g., 1/31/2018) is cell A1, the formula

```
=A1-TODAY()
```

will result in "24" (if today is January 7, 2018). Assuming, of course, the format of the cell is correct.